# Creating a template with polymorphism and op. overloading in C++

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I am studying C ++, and I wanted to ask:

How I can transform class "time" in a template?
Something like:

```
template <class genericType>
class time {
```

I'm not good in C ++, and what I'd like to do is use other types of data in main, and not just "int" as in the code below.

I would like to make something like:

```
time <char>t('a','a','a');
t.show();

er <char>t2('b','b','b');
t2.show();

time <char>t3=t+t2;
t3.show();
```

Thank you all.
This is the code i would like to transform in template:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class time{
protected:

   int hour, minuts , seconds;

public:

    time(int x=0, int y=0, int z=0){
        hour=x;
        minuts=y;
        seconds=z;
    }
   virtual void show(){
        cout<<"it's "<<hour<<":"<<minuts<<":"<<seconds<<endl;
    }


   time operator+(time &te){

         cout<<"sum everything: ";
         time bho;
         bho.hour=hour+te.hour;
         bho.minuts+=minuts+te.minuts;
         bho.seconds+=seconds+te.seconds;
         return bho;
   }

};

class er: public time {

public:

   er(int x=0,int y=0,int z=0):time(x,y,z){};

   void show() {
     cout<< "Inside er: it's  "<<hour<<":"<<minuts<<":"<<seconds<<endl;
   };
};

int main()
{

    time t(10,10,10);
    t.show();

    er t2(20,20,20);
    t2.show();

    time *pt= new er(60,60,60);
    pt->show();

    time t3=t+t2;
    t3.show();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can someone tell me why I have received a low rating to my question?
I'm learning C ++ and I have asked a simple question for something that I did not know how to do.
If a person receives a low rating for a question that he ask for, then  what is the use of this site for ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true,
The solution of @serge Ballesta is wrong.
Maybe you could try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class genericType>
class time{
 protected:

    genericType hour, minutes , seconds;

public:

    time(genericType x=0, genericType y=0, genericType z=0){
        hour=x;
        minutes=y;
        seconds=z;
    }
   virtual void  show(){
        cout<<"it's: "<<hour<<":"<<minutes<<":"<<seconds<<endl;
    }

   time operator+(time &te){

         cout<<"sum everything: "<<endl;
         time bho;
         bho.hour=hour+te.hour;
         bho.minutes+=minutes+te.minutes;
         bho.seconds+=seconds+te.seconds;
         return bho;
   }

};

template <class genericType>
class er: public time <genericType>{

   public:

   er(genericType x=0,genericType y=0, genericType z=0){
      time<genericType>::hour=x;
      time<genericType>::minutes=y;
      time<genericType>::seconds=z;
   }

  void show() {
    cout<< "Inside er: it's "<<time<genericType>::hour<<":"<<time<genericType>::minutes<<":"<<time<genericType>::seconds<<endl;
   };
};

int main()
{
    time <char>t('a','a','a');
    t.show();

    er <char>t2('b','b','b');
    t2.show();

    time <char>t3=t+t2;
    t3.show();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. But seems a little complicated. There is another simpler solution than: "time<genericType>::hour=x;" ???

Answer (score 0):

Just read a C++ tutorial and add the magic `template <class T>`...

Here is a templated version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class time{
protected:

   T hour, minuts , seconds;

public:

    time(T x=0, T y=0, T z=0){
        hour=x;
        minuts=y;
        seconds=z;
    }
   virtual void show(){
        cout<<"it's "<<hour<<":"<<minuts<<":"<<seconds<<endl;
    }


   time operator+(time &te){

         cout<<"sum everything: ";
         time bho;
         bho.hour=hour+te.hour;
         bho.minuts+=minuts+te.minuts;
         bho.seconds+=seconds+te.seconds;
         return bho;
   }

};

template <class T>
class er: public time<T> {

public:

   er(T x=0,T y=0,T z=0):time(x,y,z){};

   void show() {
     cout<< "Inside er: it's  "<<hour<<":"<<minuts<<":"<<seconds<<endl;
   };
};

int main()
{

    time<char> t('2', '2', '2');
    t.show();

    er<char> t2('1', '1', '1');
    t2.show();

    time<int> *pt= new er<int>(60,60,60);
    pt->show();

    time<char> t3=t+t2;
    t3.show();

    return 0;
}
```

NB: I used characters `'1'` (code 0x31) and `'2'` (code 0x33) because the sum gives 0x63, character `'c'` - provided you use an ASCII based system

Comment: Thanks, but this method does not work.
I get this error:
     "error: class 'er <T>' does not have any field named 'Time'" 

This is not the correct solution.
I had already tried to do this, but I received this error.
This way I'm asking here for the correct solution.